# Unity rotation screwing up when multiplying an angle by a decimal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am making an FPS game and I am trying to make an attachment that reduces recoil on weopons. The recoil pattern is based on an array of transforms with their rotation determining how much the players rotation will change. The problem is that when I multiply the recoil patterns rotations by a modifier value the player rotation will jump around at extreme angles. **This only happens when the modifier value has a decimal and not when it is a whole number.**

```
void Recoil()
{
    StopCoroutine(SprayPatternTimer(0));
    Quaternion lastRot = Quaternion.Euler(user.playerLook.eyes.localEulerAngles.x, user.playerLook.playerBody.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
    float sprayX = sprayPattern[sprayIndex].localEulerAngles.x * recoilModX; //multiplying the x and y rotation by the rotation modifiers
    float sprayY = sprayPattern[sprayIndex].localEulerAngles.y * recoilModY;

    user.playerLook.eyes.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
        sprayX + user.playerLook.eyes.rotation.eulerAngles.x, //here I am changing the players x rotation by the modified transforms rotation
        user.playerLook.eyes.localEulerAngles.y,
        user.playerLook.eyes.localEulerAngles.z);

    user.playerLook.playerBody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
        user.playerLook.playerBody.rotation.eulerAngles.x,
        sprayY + user.playerLook.playerBody.localEulerAngles.y, //here I am changing the players y rotation by the modified transforms rotation
        user.playerLook.playerBody.localEulerAngles.z);
   
    Quaternion nowRot = Quaternion.Euler(user.playerLook.eyes.localEulerAngles.x, user.playerLook.playerBody.localEulerAngles.y, 0);

    sprayIndex++;
    StartCoroutine(SprayPatternTimer(0.5f));
    if(sprayIndex >= sprayPattern.Length)
    {
        sprayIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is on lines 5-16

Comment: Euler to Quaternion to Euler is not guaranteed to return the same values.  Quick fix is to just stash your Eulers in a local variable.  Better fix is to use Quaternions exclusively.

Comment: This documentation page throws some light on the general issue with converting between quat and euler: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html

Comment: Assigning local euler y and z to world euler y and z seems like it could lead to unexpected results.